# List in C Error - Stack around the variable 'memory' was corrupted

Tags: c, list, realloc, calloc

I am trying to implement a dynamic List in C and I do not get why I get the "Stack around the variable 'memory' was corrupted." Error when I am trying to add a second Item to the list.

```
struct LIST {
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int count;
    void** items;
};

struct LIST* list_init(unsigned int size)
{
    struct LIST* createList = (struct LIST*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct LIST));
    void* memory = calloc(size, sizeof(void*));
    if (memory == 0 || createList == 0) return 0;

    createList->items = &memory;
    createList->size = size;

    return createList;
}

void list_add(struct LIST* list, void* item)
{
    if (list->count + 1 > list->size)
    {
        void* memory = realloc(list->items, (sizeof(void*)) * list->count + 1);
        list->items = &memory;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        list->items[list->count] = item;
        list->count = list->count + 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* str = "Hello";
    struct LIST* list = list_init(2);

    list_add(list, (void*)str);
    list_add(list, (void*)str);
    list_add(list, (void*)str);
    list_add(list, (void*)str);

    printf("Items in List: %d \n\n", list_count(list));

    list_clear(list);

    free(list);
    return 0;
}
```

The code never goes into the if block that could do anything with the memory variable, however in the second list_add Call it crashes when exiting the function (Note I am using the VS2022 Debugger to step through it).

I expect to have 2 items added to the list before realloc is used to extend the list by one.

Comment: In `list->items = &memory;` that's the address of a local variable which will go out of scope & life. The code has *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: ...and similarly `createList->items = &memory;`. Why are you using a double pointer for a linked list? It's usual to have a single `*` and then `createList->items = memory;` will be good.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues ...

1. In `LIST`, `items` should be just `void *` and *not* `void **`
2. In `list_add`, `memory` is a stack local variable that goes out of scope. Change `list->items = &memory` to `list->items = memory`
3. You just use `list->count + 1` in the `realloc`. We want to increment `list->size` instead and use that in the call.
4. The actual store code (in the `else` block) should be executed *unconditionally*
5. The storing code tries to dereference a `void *` pointer
6. Because the list is storing *strings* (i.e. `char *` arrays), we need to duplicate the string when storing. So, we should use `strdup`
7. Because of the new `strdup`, just doing `free(list)` at the end is insufficient. We need to loop through all elements and free the strings we duplicated in `list_add`.
8. `list_init` is replicating code in `list_add`. It should *just* do the *first* `calloc` only.
9. Because we *can* pass in string *literals* to `list_add` (e.g. `list_add(list,"Hello");`, the 2nd arg should have `const`.

---

Here is the refactored code. It is annotated with the bugs and fixes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct LIST {
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int count;
#if 0
    void **items;
#else
    void *items;
#endif
};

struct LIST *
list_init(unsigned int size)
{
#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: do _not cast the return of calloc (or malloc/realloc)
    struct LIST *createList = (struct LIST *) calloc(1, sizeof(struct LIST));
#else
    struct LIST *createList = calloc(1, sizeof(*createList));
#endif

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: this replicates code in list_add
    void *memory = calloc(size, sizeof(void *));

    if (memory == 0 || createList == 0)
        return 0;

    createList->items = &memory;
    createList->size = size;
#endif

    return createList;
}

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: this should be a const pointer because we can pass in a string
// literal
void
list_add(struct LIST *list, void *item)
#else
void
list_add(struct LIST *list, const void *item)
#endif
{

    if (list->count + 1 > list->size) {
#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: we need to increment list->size
        void *memory = realloc(list->items, (sizeof(void *)) * list->count + 1);
#else
        list->size += 3;
        void *memory = realloc(list->items, (sizeof(void *)) * list->size);
#endif

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: the variable 'memory' is on the stack and goes out of scope
        list->items = &memory;
        return;
#else
        list->items = memory;
#endif
    }

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: this should be executed unconditionally
// NOTE/BUG: we need to duplicate the 'item' string
// NOTE/BUG: we can _not_ dereference a void * pointer
    else {
        list->items[list->count] = item;
        list->count = list->count + 1;
    }
#else
    char **items = list->items;
    items[list->count] = strdup(item);
    list->count = list->count + 1;
#endif
}

#if 1
void
list_print(struct LIST *list)
{

    printf("Items in List: %d\n", list->count);

    const char **items = list->items;
    if (items != NULL) {
        for (unsigned int idx = 0;  idx < list->count;  ++idx, ++items)
            printf("Item: %s\n",*items);
    }
}

void
list_free(struct LIST *list)
{

    char **items = list->items;

    if (items != NULL) {
        for (unsigned int idx = 0;  idx < list->count;  ++idx, ++items)
            free(*items);
    }

    free(list);
}

#endif

int
main(void)
{
    const char *str = "Hello";
    struct LIST *list = list_init(2);

#if 0
// NOTE/BUG: no need to cast str and can be detrimental as in masks the
// const nature of a string literal as below
    list_add(list, (void *) str);
    list_add(list, (void *) str);
    list_add(list, (void *) str);
    list_add(list, (void *) str);
#else
    list_add(list, str);
    list_add(list, "abc");
    list_add(list, "def");
    list_add(list, "ghi");
    list_add(list, "jkl");
#endif

#if 0
    printf("Items in List: %d \n\n", list_count(list));

    list_clear(list);
#else
    list_print(list);
#endif

#if 0
    free(list);
#else
    list_free(list);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

---

In the code above, I've used `cpp` conditionals to denote old vs. new code:

```
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif
```

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through `unifdef -k`

---

Here is the program output:

```
Items in List: 5
Item: Hello
Item: abc
Item: def
Item: ghi
Item: jkl
```

---

Here is the cleaned up code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct LIST {
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int count;
    void *items;
};

struct LIST *
list_init(unsigned int size)
{
    struct LIST *createList = calloc(1, sizeof(*createList));

    return createList;
}

void
list_add(struct LIST *list, const void *item)
{

    if (list->count + 1 > list->size) {
        list->size += 3;
        void *memory = realloc(list->items, (sizeof(void *)) * list->size);

        list->items = memory;
    }

    char **items = list->items;
    items[list->count] = strdup(item);
    list->count = list->count + 1;
}

void
list_print(struct LIST *list)
{

    printf("Items in List: %d\n", list->count);

    const char **items = list->items;
    if (items != NULL) {
        for (unsigned int idx = 0;  idx < list->count;  ++idx, ++items)
            printf("Item: %s\n",*items);
    }
}

void
list_free(struct LIST *list)
{

    char **items = list->items;

    if (items != NULL) {
        for (unsigned int idx = 0;  idx < list->count;  ++idx, ++items)
            free(*items);
    }

    free(list);
}

int
main(void)
{
    const char *str = "Hello";
    struct LIST *list = list_init(2);

    list_add(list, str);
    list_add(list, "abc");
    list_add(list, "def");
    list_add(list, "ghi");
    list_add(list, "jkl");

    list_print(list);

    list_free(list);

    return 0;
}
```